# Iterate through matched views

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

How can I iterate through all views which are matched by `onView()` and perform a click on each one? In particular, I have a `ListView` where each row has a `CheckBox`. I want to write a test which clicks on each `CheckBox` in turn.

Comment: I am not an Espresso expert, but the javadoc for onView suggests that it only deals with a single view.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, it looks like that is the case. So I need to find some other method to obtain the list of views. If it doesn't already exist, I might be able figure out how `onView()` works and modify it for my purposes.

Comment: If you can get reference to a real ListView object, it's possible to iterate that to find child views that are currently visible.  But I'm actually teaching myself uiautomator first, before Espresso, at this very moment, otherwise I'd find that answer ASAP!

Comment: @DougStevenson Sounds like we are on the same path. My current tests actually do just what you suggest. I am rewriting them with Espresso. (I was even doing some UI Automator stuff last week.)

Answer (score 1):

Since I have a `ListView`, I need to use `onData()` instead of `onView()`. I also know exactly how many rows are in the `ListView`, so I can use a for loop and [`DataInteraction.atPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/DataInteraction.html#atPosition(java.lang.Integer)):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    onData(instanceOf(BaseballCard.class))
            .atPosition(i)
            .perform(click());
}
```

I can imagine other circumstances where I have several similar views in a `TableLayout` or something other than a `ListView`. It certainly would be nice to be able to iterate through the views matched by `onView()`, but I haven't found a way to do this yet.